# C++ error: ambiguous symbol. Compiler replacing '*' with '^' to continue parsing

Tags: c++

На решения данных ошибок ушло больше целого рабочего дня. Как узнал из разных ресурсов, не можно миксовать `managed` и `not-managed` классы. 
В следствии чего могут возникнуть ошибки типа:

> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um\objidl.h(12144): error C3699: '*': cannot use this indirection on type 'IDataObject'
>
> note: compiler replacing '*' with '^' to continue parsing
>
> error C2872: 'IDataObject': ambiguous symbol

Потратил несколько часов чтобы переписать `not-managed` классы, НО это не решило проблему.

Comment: Вынесите ответ в ответ, не нужно держать его в вопросе. Самоответы — нормальная практика.

Comment: @ixSci ответил. спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Так как это достаточно популярная проблема среди новеньких, которые только начинают работать с C++/CLI. В моем случае ряд всех этих ошибок был вызван не миксом классов, а библиотекой marshal_cppstd, которая переводит String^ в std::string. После удаления #include  код начал компилироваться без ошибок.

Если вы столкнулись с данной проблемой, не спишите переписывать и подстраивать not-managed классы, а так же чистить header файлы от using namespace ... и проверьте не используется ли где-то в коде именно эта библиотека.